# Euler Bricks in High Dimensions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

It is a well-known and *open* problem to determine whether there exists a rectangular cuboid where the distance from any corner to any other corner is an integer.  Such a beast, if it exists, is called an Euler brick.

What happens if we work in larger dimensions?  It is easy to generalize the definition of a rectangular cuboid to higher dimensions, and it appears that this question is open!  Thus, my questions is:

**Do we know if there is no 4-dimensional Euler brick?  How about 10-dimensional?**

Comment: Aren't the faces of an Euler 4-brick themselves Euler 3-bricks? (I may be being stupid here)

Comment: According to https://www.erpublication.org/admin/vol_issue1/upload%20Image/IJETR011924.pdf , there are no 4-dimensional Euler bricks. (Also, the ABC conjecture is true.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That claim does throw some questionability on their work, doesn't it.  :-)

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, so this problem should be easier to solve (given it is likely that there is no Euler brick).

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a local obstruction at some prime, making this problem easy. Unfortunately there is not - for each $p$ there are bricks where all diagonals are $p$-adic integers. For $p>2$ one can take the side lengths to be $1,p,p^2,\dots$, and then every diagonal will be of the form $p^n \sqrt{ 1 + m p}$ for integers $n,m$ and so will be a $p$-adic integer. For $p=2$ the same thing works but with powers of $4$.